# Zero wont connect to AP (multiple devices with the same ssid)

Tags: networking, pi-zero-w, wireless, wireless-adapter

I have Razberry PI Zero W and I am trying to setup wifi connection. Our apartment has multiple APs with the same name. Routers work on the 2.4 and 5 GHZ frequency. I cannot access those routers.

I tried connecting to phone AP and it works, however I cannot connect to other APs.

```
country=SI
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="name"
    scan_ssid=1
    psk="pass"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I am editing a file /Volumes/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: I'd also suggest checking that the AP your connecting to isn't set to auto 5ghz/2.4ghz and that the bands have been separated I.e.  a specific AP for each band. I've had issues in the past where a pi0 wouldn't connect to a network because the bands weren't separated and the pi basically got confused. That it works with the phone would suggest the phone is broadcasting on the 2.4ghz which is usually the default. You have to explicitly set it to 5ghz if you want it.

Comment: I take it you can connect your phone the AP without issue? Did you ask this yesterday?

Comment: @rohtua - how can a pi zero be confused by a 5Ghz signal it can't even see!!!???

Comment: @Bravo no it can't see 5ghz networks but if you've got one AP that handles both 5ghz and 2.4ghz on a single SSID (as most routers do by default) it can see the AP but from my own experience it doesn't connect because the router tries to put it onto the 5ghz by default which the pi can't connect to so it just drops the connection. I've found that for best compatibility for Pi's and other 2.4ghz devices you should split the bands so they are broadcast on unique SSID's which tends to improve things anyway.

Comment: As in your earlier deleted question you have provided no details, no diagnostics. Look at `dmesg` and `systemctl status dhcpcd`. Don't use `scan_ssid=1` unless the network is hidden. Did you try connecting in the GUI?

Comment: @rohtua Yes, the phone is broadcasting on 2.4ghz. At first I havent thought that auto 2.4/5 would not have any affect on my configuration... Could I use bssic to connect to specific band (2.4ghz)?

Comment: @MatejJ I'm not sure what bssic is? There isn't a lot you can do without accessing the router to split the bands into seperate SSID's. The only thing I can suggest is to contact whoever controls the routers and ask them to make the change. You could setup an AP you can control, connect it to one of the routers and set it up with seperarte SSID's and connect the pi that way (but there may be other issues there if you don't have permission etc. To make that kind of change/addition to the network) That's all assuming there isn't something else interfering with it.

Comment: I had this issue with an old ISP provided router and there was just something about the auto setting for the band that some 2.4 only devices like the pi 0 just didn't like so I'd certainly look at splitting the bands out and hopefully you'll find that the pi connects with no issue to the 2.4 SSID

Comment: Nevermind, solved it

Answer (score 1):

The Pi zero doesn't support 5GHz WiFi, so it simply doesn't see the 5GHz networks and doesn't care about their names. The reason your Pi doesn't connect is likely elsewhere.

I would start by setting the country code via Localisation Options item from the menu, and configure the connection using `raspi-config`.

Also try connecting your phone to the router, and make sure your phone is using 2.4GHz WiFi, otherwise the fact that it connects to a 5GHz AP doesn't mean the Pi would be able to connect to 2.4GHz with the same password.

Comment: I think the OP was saying he can connect the pi to a phone AP - also looks like OP has set the country code to SI

Comment: @Bravo You are right, and connecting the phone to the router is something he should nevertheless try. I've seen the country code line, though it's not clear whether it's a command or part of a file, and, assuming it's part of a file I don't know if changing the locale via the menu has other effects.

Comment: Yes, I did successfully connect to phone AP, and I am using 2.4ghz band.

Comment: Nevermind, solved it